# How to properly exit firebase-admin nodejs script when all transaction is completed

Tags: firebase-admin

Is there anyway to check if all firebase transaction is completed in firebase-admin nodejs script, and properly disconnect from firebase and exit the nodejs script?

Currently, the firebase-admin nodejs script will just keep running even after all the transaction has been completed.

Answer (score 38):

If you're keeping track of all the promises and they complete successfully, what's happening is that the app is keeping a connection open, you can kill the app, by using:

```
app.delete()
```

For example if you used the default app you can do this:

```
firebase.app().delete()
```

Comment: this is the real answer. `process.exit()` isn't the best way to shutdown a node process.

Comment: Use `admin.app().delete()` if you only use `firebase-admin`

Answer (score 6):

The [`DatabaseReference.transaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction) method returns a promise which is fulfilled when the transaction is completed. You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method to wait for any number of these transaction promises to complete and then call [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) to end the program.

Here is a full example:

```js
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

    // Initialize the SDK
    var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
    });

    // Create two transactions
    var addRef = admin.database().ref("add");
    var addPromise = addRef.transaction(function(current) {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    });

    var subtractRef = admin.database().ref("subtract");
    var subtractPromise = subtractRef.transaction(function(current) {
      return (current || 0) - 1;
    });

    // Wait for all transactions to complete and then exit
    return Promise.all([addPromise, subtractPromise])
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Transaction promises completed! Exiting...");
        process.exit(0);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Transactions failed:", error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
```