# Close Database Connection (Firebase+Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on **Node.js** and **firebase** and I am currently stuck in an issue, where after writing the data in database my program does not end on a terminal, is there a way I can end this.

I guess, maybe I need to end the firebase connection but I don't have an idea how would I do that.

Here is the program,

```js
module.exports=
{
create_firebase_entry: function ()
  {
    console.log("Firebase Entry")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var secondaryAppConfig = 
      {
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "firebase_databse_url"
      };
      
      if (admin.apps.length===0){secondary = admin.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");}

      // Retrieve the database.
      var db = secondary.database();
      var ref = db.ref("data_records");
      var usersRef = ref.child("My_Data");
      
      usersRef.set({Data1:"Trail Data"})
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The script opens a connection to the Firebase Realtime Database, and then performs asynchronous read and write operations over that connection. Since the script has no way to know when you're done, you will have to signal this yourself.

The most common way to do this (that I know of) is to call `process.exit()` when you're done. E.g.

```
usersRef.set({Data1:"Trail Data"})
  .then(function() {
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

Also see

- [How to properly exit firebase-admin nodejs script when all transaction is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630485/how-to-properly-exit-firebase-admin-nodejs-script-when-all-transaction-is-comple)
- [Exit from a NodeJS script when all asynchronous tasks are done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870227/exit-from-a-nodejs-script-when-all-asynchronous-tasks-are-done)
- [node process doesn't exit after firebase once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046639/node-process-doesnt-exit-after-firebase-once)

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Frank but I think using `process.exit(0);` under `.finally()` block will provide more guarantee. Because when error occur It will never close.

```
usersRef.set({Data1:"Trail Data"})
  .then(result => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // ...
  })
  .finally(() => {
    process.exit(0)
  })
```